# Angular Material DataTable databinding

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) and attempting to get the DataTable working with an Http response object. I have the DataSource setup and the table rows are being populated but none of the content is being display in the table. I get a blank row entry for each object in the collection but I can see the data using Augury to inspect the table properties.

Here is the component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk';
import { ResponseSearchResult } from './response-search-result';
import { SearchService } from '../shared/search.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';


@Component({
  selector: 'search-results',
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss']
})

export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: ["ResponseConditionName", "ResponseText", "RelatedLinks"];
  searchTerm: string;
  templateItems: number[];
  loadingData: boolean;
  searchResults: any = null;
  dataSource: SearchDataSource | null;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataSource = new SearchDataSource(this.searchService);

    this.searchService.loadingSearchResults.subscribe({
      next: (value) => this.loadingData = value
    });
  }
}

export class SearchDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    super();
  }

  subject = new BehaviorSubject<ResponseSearchResult[]>([]);

  connect(): Observable<ResponseSearchResult[]> {

    this.searchService.searchResults.subscribe({
      next: (value) => {
        this.subject.next(value);
      }
    });
    return Observable.merge(this.subject);
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.subject.complete();
    this.subject.observers = [];
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="dataSource">
  <md-table #searchResultsTable [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="ResponseConditionName">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.ResponseConditionName}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>
                
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="ResponseText">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Response </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.ResponseText}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>
  
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="RelatedLinks">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> RelatedLinks </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
        <a *ngFor="let link of row.RelatedLinks">
          {{link.LinkName}}
        </a>
      </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
  </md-table>
</div>
```

Here is the data object being returned by the service:

```
export class ResponseSearchResult {
  UnitName: string;
  ResponseConditionName: string;
  ResponseText: string;
  RelatedLinks: RelatedLink[];
  NavigationUrl: NavigationUrl;
  Owner: string;
  WorkflowStatus: string;
}
```

And here is the service itself:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { SearchQuery } from '../search/search-query';
import { ResponseSearchResult } from '../results/response-search-result';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  public searchResults: BehaviorSubject<ResponseSearchResult[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ResponseSearchResult[]>(null);
  public loadingSearchResults: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  submitResponseSearch(searchQuery: SearchQuery) {
    this.loadingSearchResults.next(true);
    let searchTypes = this.getSelectedSearchTypes(searchQuery);

    this.http.get<ResponseSearchResult[]>(
      `/api/search/GetSearchResults?searchString=${searchQuery.searchTerm}&searchTypes=${searchTypes}`).subscribe(response => {

      this.searchResults.next(response);
      this.loadingSearchResults.next(false);
    });
  }

  getSelectedSearchTypes(searchQuery: SearchQuery) {
    return searchQuery.searchTypes.filter(type => type.IsSelected).map(({ Name }) => Name).join(",");
  }


}
```

Here is a screencap of the console output from the service return in SearchDataSource:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an object from the data array `value` or `this.loadingData` returned by the observable? Everything looks good in your code. The only reason I can think of is, object keys are not matching.

Comment: As Nehal mentioned, your `displayedColumns` and `dataSource` columns likely have different key values.

Comment: Can you please add `console.log(value)` before `this.subject.next(value);` in the `SearchDataSource` class and let us know what output you see in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `:` instead of `=` when initializing `displayedColumns`.

Change

`displayedColumns: ["ResponseConditionName", "ResponseText", "RelatedLinks"];`

to

`displayedColumns = ["ResponseConditionName", "ResponseText", "RelatedLinks"];`

Simplified working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Qer4gLCVZryZXvqGUCN) of your code.

Hope this will resolve the issue of data not appreaing in the table.

Comment: :). I exhausted all other possibilities for an hour before finally noticing this syntax error lol

Comment: I spent the better part of a day or so trying to track it down to no avail. New to TypeScript/Angular4 so it was an easy syntax mistake that I overlooked.

Comment: Hi @Nehal how can i add new data/row using post method